# GAE + SAML + JAVA + OpenSAML

Tags: java, google-app-engine, saml, opensaml

I am creating a web application on GAE. In this application i have to implement the SSO feature using SAML 2.0. I am suffering lot on web but i didn't find any example. I get the knowledge how SAML work, which library i have to use in java. But before starting i want to know if this feature is possible in GAE. I know google apps are based on SAML and provide SSO functionality. But i didn't find any link where it stated that GAE also support SAML and we can create SAML application on GAE. Thanks

Comment: - Google Apps account (which you must have to host GAE apps) can be configured for SAML. But that's not related to having your own app consume SAML <br/>

- GAE can be used to host java-based web apps. These web-apps can use dependency on third-party libraries (e.g. opensaml). <br/>

What exactly is your question? Are you getting errors deploying an app that has opensaml dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some integration with my demo google app engine account. Here i used Java based SAML2 IDP in my local which has been connected to LDAP user store. And using this IDP, i could login to google app account. Here what i understood. We need to configure about the IDP details (uri and so on) in the google account and upload a certificate of my IDP.  Then i want to create same user which was in my IDP, in the google app account (I guess, it is for authorization purpose). Once i tried to login to google app, then it redirects me to my local SAML2 IDP and i need to provide user credentials to IDP. Then i would be directed to google app and can login to it. [Here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/help/articles/shibboleth2.0) is some guide how to enable SAML2 SSO with  shibboleth.  I guess this would be help you.